# Setting up a SIP NAT proxy

Tags: nat, voip, sip

We currently run a VoIP server using an upstream providers SIP proxy for our clients who are behind NAT. We now have the problem that we re ending the relationship with the upstream provider, and will no longer have access to their nice NAT proxy!

We've decided we should probably build one ourselves. We've done some fairly extensive googling on this subject and it seems to be you need to use OpenSIPs and MediaProxy to build one. Problem is documentation on the subject seems to vary between really vague and assuming lots of back knowledge, or really outdated and therefore useless.

I'm looking for a thorough guide or set of worked examples on how to get a NAT proxy for VoIP set up working from scratch. Any pointers to known god guides, or just outright step-by-step answers will be appreciated!

**Update**

To clarify, what I'm looking for is a guide to building the server that the phone talks to through the "Proxy" setting of most SIP phones.

Comment: this appears to be unsolvable.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Siproxd](http://siproxd.sourceforge.net/) in the past in these situations (several SIP endpoints, registering with an external SIP softswitch, and a non SIP-aware router in between), and it has worked very well. It's quite simple to install and set up. The project page has detailed installation and configuration [documentation](http://siproxd.sourceforge.net/index.php?op=odoc).

If you want to go *really* simple, and you are able to switch out what router you use, fire up a [pfSense](http://pfsense.org/) router. pfSense has a siproxd package available, which is a single-click install.

Comment: For those are *nix challenged like me, a pfSense router will let you install siproxd as a package.

Comment: ...as I mentioned in my answer. :)

Comment: we need the NAT proxy to be held outside of the customer's networks, and usable by any of the NAT customers remotely. This unfortunately make a router with ALG not a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to run your SIP proxy on the LAN side of your NAT router.

- install debian or ubuntu system
- `sudo apt-get install siproxd`
- `echo ENABLED=1 | sudo tee /etc/default/siproxd`
- edit `/etc/siproxd.conf` as shown in http://siproxd.sourceforge.net/siproxd_guide/siproxd_guide_c7s3.html
- `sudo /etc/init.d/siproxd start`
- configure clients to use your proxy

Comment: actually we need it the other way round, so connectivity goes: handset>natRouter>internet>natProxy>PBX